# Can a PC be modified and used as a server?

Tags: windows, networking

can a pc used as a server? If yes what should I have in mind?

I am using Windows

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: @Bora 4 people answered

Comment: wow.. that.. should suffice..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  A server is just a machine that serves out requests.  I can install a web server and a website on my phone, thus also making it a server.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you have in mind really :) 
what type of server do you want to set up? with windows there are some limitations but there are some functions you can do. 
Of course if you move that pc to a full linux machine there is nothing stopping you from doing server like functionality but the capabilities of the hardware (processor, memory, your network, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

This question is way to broad.  But the short answer is yes.  You can install a server OS/software on a  PC and PC OS/software on server hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Generally you can install Windows Server on any Windows compatible system so long as it meets the system requirements for that version of Windows Server.  For example, here are the [requirements for Windows Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb414778) .  If your system meets those requirements, you can install Windows Server 2008 on it.

However, systems that are built to be *production* servers tend to be more robust and have things such as RAID, tape drives for backup, and dual power supplies that provide redundancy in case of component failure.  For a non-critical functions, or for learning, any machine with a decent amount of RAM and a good sized hard drive should work.  However, if the system is not stable it won't make a good server of any type.